# Ionic 5 set collapsable header color on iOS

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

My app UI is complex so I'm giving an example to illustrate my problem. On Ionic 5 I have this code taken directly from the official [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/title#collapsible-large-titles)

```html
<ion-header translucent="true">
  <ion-toolbar>   
    <ion-buttons collapse="true" slot="end">
      <ion-button>Click Me</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons> 
    <ion-title>Settings</ion-title>               
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">              
    <ion-toolbar>      
      <ion-buttons collapse="true" slot="end">
        <ion-button>Click Me</ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title size="large">Settings</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  ...

</ion-content>
```

If I set the color of the toolbars in a way like `<ion-toolbar color="primary">` I get something like this

[image]

How can I set the color for the space above the colored toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue as well, controlled all my toolbars css from the `global.scss` to set background color:

```
ion-toolbar {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}
```

where
 `--ion-color-primary` is my desired color

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to add that this also works from the component `scss` if you want to set different styles for different pages